# MongoDb stores Float field as Double. Getting IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Data is stored correctly, however when I get the data back from Mongodb, I get the

> IllegalArgumentException. cannot set java.lang.Float to java.lang.Double.

Does it have any converters, which will convert automatically from `double` to `float`.

Comment: AFAIK mongo doesn't store any information related java datatypes in it.

Comment: please added some lines of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deserialize the object, and assign to the lowest leaf of the tree. and then use the converter to convert from double to float and vice versa.